# REACT - How Should i pass values from html in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
function joinRoom(givenRoomId) {
        const url = `http://127.0.0.1:8000/play/${givenRoomId}/joinRoom/`
        fetch(url, {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json",
                "Authorization": "Token 900e748b0ad69b5d233b15c5483873395d572fe8"
            }
        }).then(res => {return res.json()}).then(data => console.log(data)).catch(error => console.log("Error"))
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>RoomID - RoomName - NoOfPlayers</h1>
    {state.rooms.map(room => (
       <div key={room.id}>
         <h2>{room.id} - {room.roomId}</h2>
         <button onClick={joinRoom}>Join</button>
       </div>
     ))}
 </div>
```

I am new to React and I need to pass room.id's value in function so i can join that specific room. I have rooms which is list of all rooms which is fetched from API.

Comment: You can use a lambda: `onClick={e=> joinRoom(room.id)}`.

Comment: @David784 your answer is correct. But this is no Python. These are called arrow functions here not lambda.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{state.rooms.map(room => (
       <div key={room.id}>
         <h2>{room.id} - {room.roomId}</h2>
         <button onClick={()=>joinRoom(room.id}>Join</button>
       </div>
))}
```

also, you should read the react documentary to understanding better